# Button not working in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Hi i created a simple help manual page in jpg format , named it helppicture , then i created  an xml file : help.xml and added image as  android:background .
Help button is on the main menu , I implemented the help button inside an onclick view switch case like this :

```
    case R.id.takehelp :
        Intent intent3=new Intent(NUGA_MainMenuActivity.this,HelpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
```

Now in my **HelpActivity** class ,

i implemented the following code :

```
public class HelpActivity extends Activity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);          

    }   
}
```

But when  i run the application and click the **Help button** ,nothing happens, please help me.

Comment: post your xml code of help menu button.

Comment: if you have require quick response then post .xml and manifest file

Comment: Have you added button click event listener?

Answer (score 0):

In your helpActivity, you haven't write anything about the button event. you should add the code in your onCreate function:

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 

button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){ 
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // do something after clicking the button
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing. "Help button is on the main menu , I implemented the help button inside an onclick view"

If Help is on the menu, implement startactivity in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item).

Hope you can see the layout preview and there is no error in the help.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you reigstered HelpActivity on the file of AndroidManifest.xml.Try this instead.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer just a little?

Comment: for example:
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MyMultitouchDemo"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name='HelpActvity'></activity>